# IFRAME and NATIVE Mode in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have created a google apps script to display some indicators with images. 
I have used the following code
    function doGet() {
      var output=  HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('cfcgfcg');
      output.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
      return output;
    }
The code works fine in NATIVE mode, but it does not work with IFRAME mode. I have tried the guidlines to migrate from NATIVE to IFRAME given in the following link
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/iframe#setting_the_link_target_attribute

But the code doesn't work

Following is the code I have used 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C9_tabVhPq1NhKBjqNATvdC5G9542A8rRqhxpa-BSknx8m19Kts6bsB-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you used a wrong url to load JQuery lib, Use console to see the error messages
using this one hosted on https server works in `IFRAME` mode :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
```

Check if it runs on load by adding a log for example

```
function update() {
    console.log("update executed");
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    var data=google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getMyData();
    window.setTimeout(update, 500);
}
update();
```