# Google Apps Script IFRAME Migration in Google Spreadsheet not working

Tags: iframe, google-apps-script, sandbox, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to follow the guidelines Google has given for migrating to IFRAME for Google Apps Script dialogs.  However, all dialogs that I migrate no longer function - only the title displays and the following error is spewed to the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined".

Here is the link to a simple example of the problem: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n5Lr6LuMj4Cyag4Z_54jRKvWiwV-b8dquREF5T4pzMY/edit?usp=sharing

It's a blank spreadsheet that has an added "Dialog" menu, select "Show Dialog" from the "Dialog" menu to see the behavior.

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Dialog")
    .addItem("Show Dialog","showDialog")
    .addToUi();
}

function showDialog()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function onOK()
      {
        console.log("ok");
      }

      function onCancel()
      {
        console.log("cancel");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
     <input type="text" id="editme" size="8">
     <button type="button" id="ok" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 150px; width: 60px;" onclick="onOK()">OK</button>
     <button type="button" id="cancel" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 100px; width: 60px;" onclick="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's already an existing issue logged just a few months ago in **google-apps-script-issues** regarding [HTMLService migration to IFRAME sandbox fails: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5607). And based from that issues thread, a few developers also encountered it and this hasn't been resolved yet.

In any case, you may want to try to check and note of [HTML Service: Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#sandbox_mode) and [HTML Service: Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript), there can only be something that could have been missed out.

Also try the suggested solution in this SO post - [IFRAME and NATIVE Mode in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369633/iframe-and-native-mode-in-google-apps-script). I hope something from these works for you.

Comment: Yes, I logged the existing issue in google-apps-script issues 6 months ago.  They have marked it as a defect with no comment.  They are 3 weeks from shutting down NATIVE mode and don't have a functional IFRAME mode for those of us that use it in Google Spreadsheet.  I posted here to see if anyone can't spot a problem with my example or this is truly a complete lack of diligence from Google devs.